# Уязвимость в капче

Tags: jquery, уязвимости, php

Здравствуйте!

На прошлой неделе написал свою КАПЧУ ([демо](http://www.makannikov.ru/demo/capcha_na_php_i_jQuery/index.php), [исходники](http://www.makannikov.ru/ishodniki/capcha_na_php_i_jQuery.zip)) по принципу, как у Евгения Попова на [сайте](http://www.evgeniypopov.com/). Но вчера открыл почтовый ящик и уже первый спам.

Я примерно понимаю почему СПАМ прошел, скорее всего, это связано с тем, что для успешного заполнения формы, пользователь должен выбрать одну из четырех картинок, к которым прикреплены радио кнопки. То есть существует вероятность того, что спам бот в случайном порядке выбирает эту радио кнопку и в некоторых случаях попадает на нужную, и СПАМ проходит.

У Евгения Попова на сайте радио кнопки скрыты (`display: none;`), а у меня нет! Может быть из-за этого? Хотя кнопки эти не видит пользователь в браузере, но в HTML коде-то они есть!

Может быть радио кнопку изначально убрать? А при клике на верную картинку с помощью jQuery ее вывести `$('...').html('<input type="radio">');` Тогда спам бот не сделает клик по картинке, и соответственно данные от радио кнопки не пройдут.

Уважаемые профессионалы, подскажите, пожалуйста, как же решить эту проблему!

Comment: Забавно... Рукописный текст машина распознать может, а цвет пикселя - ой как сложно? Такая капча в целом недоразумение с точки зрения безопасности.
Кроме того, кто Вам сказал, что ради распознавания Вашей капчи написали бота? "первый спам" - это одно-два письма? Значит это отправил человек.

Comment: Я точно знаю что это не человек, вот ссылка: http://www.gid28.ru/index.php?tab=spravochnik&firma=475 - я такого добра уже столько на почтовый ящик поймал...

Comment: Сделайте классическую капчу, пофантазируйте над формулой искривления. Любая защита от ботов с предоставлением правильного варианта ответа - это смешно. На край - лучше уж координаты клика отлавливать, а нет чекбокс выбирать - и то ломается минут за 10.

Comment: Когда я говорил про СПАМ я не имел ввиду БОТА конкретно для моей капчи. 

Получается такие картинки в принципе использовать нельзя, так как здесь уже распознается ЦВЕТ, я Вас правильно понял! (Хотя если честно я тоже думал об этом). И соответственно в вопросе (Выберите КРАСНЫЙ флажок) я зря использую цвет?

Comment: Спасибо за совет, Буду дальше мучать эту проблему! Так как на том сайте на котором мне нужна капча, она должна быть очень простой, но эффективной.

Comment: Цвет - точно зря. Если так хочется картинки - то более-менее надежный вариант - набор изображений всевозможных предметов + куча названий-синонимов + рандомное положение изображений предмета на картинке "капчи" с отслеживанием координат клика. Чем меньше изображение и больше картинка - тем сложнее угадать область клика, чем больше вариантов изображений и вариаций названий для них - тем дольше будет собираться информация для разработки бота. А если еще и искривление добавить... 

В общем, ключевая ошибка все-таки в предоставлении варианта правильного ответа в тексте страницы.

Comment: Спасибо за полезную информацию!!

Comment: @makan, Вам стоит беспокоиться наверное по поводу SQL Injection больше, чем по поводу спама. Отловил вывод таблицы с компаниями, распарсить - нет проблем. Не хотите остаться без своих данных - следите за безопасностью. На хэшкоде много вопросов о инъекциях подобного рода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть много способов обойтись вообще без капчи. Самые очевидные:

1. Скрытые поля
2. Проверка на работу JS (в основном спамилки не имеют поддержку js)
3. Проверка на работу кук (то же самое что и пунктом выше)

Вообще я пробовал писать капчи, пользоваться reCAPTCHA.. Но в итоге akismet сократил количество спама на 90%, остальное сделало скрытое поле.

Comment: Тут появилась идея: а если картинки вынести за пределы формы, а абсолютным позиционированием, нанести её на форму, и при клике по нужной картинке создать скрытое поле с нужным значением.

Comment: @makan - суть скрытых полей - ставить в форму поля с type="hidden" и проверять их заполнение. Если заполнены - это бот, т.к. простой человек не заполнил бы

Comment: Теперь понял, спасибо. Но ведь тогда есть вероятность того, что бот не тронет это поле, и спам все равно пройдет!

Comment: @makan, есть возможность скрыть поле стилями, тогда бот не отследит его аттрибуты, и соответственно введёт данные. Особенно если name="(email|e-mail|mail|login|name|user_name|username)"

Comment: Тоесть можно создать обычное поле type="text" name="email", а с помощью CSS, например(display: none;) спрятать его?

Comment: @makan, Вы совершенно правы

Comment: Ой спасибо Вам огромное!!!! От души!!! Очень помогло!!!

Comment: Вообще да, называть поля, не предназначенные для заполнения очевидными названиями, и прятать их при помощи css - это гуд :]

Comment: Конечно! http://habrahabr.ru/post/151084/

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(false);
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$action_url = "http://www.gid28.ru/content/spravochnik/pageFirm/responses/post.php";

$fields = array();
$fields["email"] = "";
$fields["name"] = "Привет, я бот!";
$fields["text"] = "Как я и говорил, эта капча легко ломается";
$fields["firm_id"] = "966";
$fields["prov"] = "";
$fields["sendResponse"] = "Оставить отзыв";

$cap_value = array(
                    'колонки' => 1,
                    'сканер' => 2,
                    'пульт' => 3,
                    'принтер' => 4,
                    'наушники' => 5,
                    'телефон' => 6,
                    'фотоаппарат' =>7,
                    );

$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3'); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.gid28.ru/index.php?tab=spravochnik&firma='.$fields["firm_id"]); 
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    preg_match_all('<img id="(.*)" class="pointer" src="content/modules/capcha/images/(.*).png">', $html, $media);
    $cap = array();
    foreach($media[2] as $varname=>$varvalue) {
        $cap[$varvalue] = $media[1][$varname];
    }

    preg_match('/Выберите <span>(.*)<\/span> \(защита от спама\)/', $html, $word);
    $word = $word[1];

$fields["prov"] = $cap[$cap_value[$word]];

$f = '';
foreach($fields as $varname => $varvalue) {
    $f .= '&'.$varname.'='.$varvalue;
}
$f = trim($f,'&');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$action_url); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$f);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
```

Собственно, вот примерный код бота...) Пару строк удалил, чтобы народ особо не развлекался, так что сообщения он все-таки не отправляет... ;) Но а у Вас теперь есть стимул быстренько "капчу" переписать к нормальному виду...)

Comment: Да уж, вот это "доброе утро"... еще сутки мучений... Еще раз огромное спасибо Вам за наглядный пример.

А если вместо name="prov", выдавать случайное имя, затем это имя поместить в сессию, ну а потом проверять?

Comment: Посидел... подумал... Ведь Ваш скрипт написан конкретно для моего сайта. Но ведь, как Вы уже и говорили, врядли кто то станет писать БОТА именно под мою капчу. Я думаю, что данной капчи хватит, чтобы отсеять процентов 90 спама, который будет рассылаться стандартными методами. А этого вполне достаточно для меня, на данный момент.

И если честно, моих знаний PHP вряд ли хватит, чтобы написать такую капчу про которую Вы говорили: 

(набор изображений всевозможных предметов + куча названий-синонимов + рандомное положение изображений предмета на картинке "капчи" с отслеживанием координат клика).

Comment: Всё равно не понимаю, что плохого в классическом варианте капчи с вводом текста? К тому же, капча все равно не спасет - на всех моих проектах с большой посещаемостью со спамом борются посредством премодерации.

Answer (score 0):

В общем я сделал так.

1. Создал текстовое поле name="email" дал ему класс(`display: none;`)
2. Сделал 6 однотонных картинок за пределами формы, но с помощью css (`position: absolute`) вернул эти картинки на форму.

А кнопку отправить немного сместил вниз, чтобы она не налезала на картинки, ну и если пользователь выберет нужную картинку, я с помощью jQuery подставляю скрытое поле (`type="hidden"`) в форму.

Пример - [здесь](http://www.gid28.ru/index.php?tab=spravochnik&firma=966) (внизу страницы).

Всем, кто откликнулся на мой вопрос, огромное спасибо!

Comment: Эх... Объясняю, как это ломается:

Руками собираем все картинки, что Вы создали. А их всего 7. И получаем все названия этих изображений.

Получаем массив вида:
(1=>'колонки', 2='сканер', ...)

Пишем бота:

Парсим страницу сохраняя куки, выбираем, какой же id картинки нужно вписать в POST-данные "prov". Отправляем. 

Ой, как долго ломалась "капча"...) 

Повторю еще раз: НЕЛЬЗЯ хранить допустимые варианты ответа на антиспам в тексте страницы.